# Serving staticfiles in django causes 400 error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my django app to heroku, however, when I try and set debug=False locally, I'm getting a 400 Bad Request. My assumption is that it is the serving of staticfiles that is causing this, given that the only message showing up in my logs are

```
The joined path (/DataTables/datatables.min.css) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/me/development/company/project/app/staticfiles)
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 26
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 85`
```

here is my settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'lockdown',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'dj_database_url',
    'app',
    'reversion',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'lockdown.middleware.LockdownMiddleware',
]


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
]



STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'


LOCKDOWN_ENABLED = True
LOCKDOWN_PASSWORDS =('xxxxx', 'yyyy')
APPEND_SLASH = True
#
# Logging
#

LOGGING = { 
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'null': { 'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
            },  
        'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'logging/debug.log',
        }   
     },  
'loggers': {
    'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
        'handlers': ['null'],
        'propagate': False,
    },  
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },  
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },  
}   
}
```

any guess on what is causing this?

Comment: you are missing a bunch of configurations for your django application, start from here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python, this will explain you how to do it properly

Comment: I know, I was being selective with what I wanted to include. Only the relevant parts. If it would help, I can include what's missing

Comment: you need to be specific about it, you can't be selective

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out? I'm having the same problem.